# Is it possible to do probabilistic programming by variable elimination with plain Mathematica 10 or later?

Tags: conditional, probability-or-statistics

Using frameworks like [Figaro](https://www.cra.com/sites/default/files/pdf/Figaro_Tutorial.pdf) it is possible to do probabilistic programming by variable elimination to build a probabilistic model and then run inferences against it in a very intuitive way.
Example:

```
import com.cra.figaro.language._
import com.cra.figaro.algorithm.factored.VariableElimination
import com.cra.figaro.library.compound.If

val sunnyToday = Flip(0.2)
println(VariableElimination.probability(sunnyToday, true))
```

Will print 0.2

But then you can add:

```
val greetingToday = If(sunnyToday, Select(0.6->"Hello, world!", 0.4->"Howdy, universe!"),
                                       Select(0.2->"Hello, world!", 0.8->"Oh no, not again!"))
```

And state that you have observed "Hello, world!"

```
greetingToday.observe("Hello, world!")
println(VariableElimination.probability(sunnyToday,true))
```

And you will get 0.4285

And after that you can remove that observation:

```
greetingToday.unobserve()
println(VariableElimination.probability(sunnyToday,true))
```

and you will get 0.2

And you can even chain this further and represent conditional probabilities for the next day...

I have the nagging feeling that Mathematica's [Probability](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html) should be able to describe this high level operations intuitively and make the same calculations, but I have been unable to find such an example anywhere...
Is it possible to do this with plain mathematica? Or is Probability too low level and a higher level framework has yet to be built on top of it to achieve something like this?

Comment: Well, it's just Bayes' theorem at work there, and that comes down to a straightforward formula.

Comment: Which makes it all the more surprising that Mathematica doesn't support it out of the box @DanielLichtblau nor have any similar examples or tutorials

Comment: Have a look to the paper of john Cassel  "Probabilistic Programming
with Stochastic Memoization
Implementing Nonparametric Bayesian
Inference"  in the Mathematica Journal

Comment: Somwhat related: [128945](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128945/764).

Comment: The link to John Cassel's article is [The Mathematica Journal, Vol. 16](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2014/01/probabilistic-programming-with-stochastic-memoization/).