# Problems encoding a Bayesian Network with just five nodes using ProbabilityDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

### Question summary

I had recently asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128844/764) where problems encoding a Bayesian Network were linked to the use of `MultinomialDistribution`. While that problem can be avoided using `EmpiricalDistribution`, there remains an issue with using `ProbabilityDistribution` for larger networks as it seems:  While `Probability` can be used for inference with 4 nodes, it will not evaluate for the "full" example network of 5 nodes -- which still is far removed from real application demands. Why is this so? What can be done about it?

### Bayesian Network Example

Again I would like to use the (simple) example that is given on page 53 in *Probabilistic Graphical Models (2009)*, by *Daphne Koller* and *Neir Friedman*:

[image: BayesianNetwork]

The network has five nodes (*random variables*):

- *Difficulty* of a class taken by a student (0 = easy, 1 = hard)
- *Intelligence* of the student (0 = low, 1 = high)
- *Grade* achieved by the student (1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C)
- *SAT* score of the student (0 = low, 1 = high)
- *Letter* of recommendation by the teacher (0 = False, 1 = True)

We would like to use this network to do probabilistic inference (causal or evidential) like: *"What is the probability of the student achieving an A, given that he is intelligent?"*

### Encoding the Bayesian Network in Mathematica

Essentially the Bayesian Network is a sparse way to define the joint probability distribution function for the random variables using the chain rule of probability theory:

$
\begin{align}
P(I,D,G,S,L) = P(I) \times P(D) \times P(G|I,D) \times P(S|I) \times P(L|G)
\end{align}
$

I am encoding this in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
(* nodes without parents *)
distI = BernoulliDistribution[ 0.3 ]; (* prior probability of high intelligence *)
distD = BernoulliDistribution[ 0.4 ]; (* prior probability of hard class *)

(* nodes with parents = conditional probability distributions *)
(* conditional distribution of the grade *)
cpdG = Function[ { i, d },
    With[
      {
        p = Piecewise[
                {
                  { {  0.3,  0.4,  0.3  }, i == 0 && d == 0 },
                  { {  0.05, 0.25, 0.7  }, i == 0 && d == 1 },
                  { {  0.9,  0.08, 0.02 }, i == 1 && d == 0 },
                  { {  0.5,  0.3,  0.2  }, i == 1 && d == 1 }
                }
            ]
      },
      EmpiricalDistribution[ p -> Range[3] ]
    ]
];

(* conditional distribution for the SAT score *)
cpdS = Function[ i,
   With[
    {
     θ = Piecewise[
           {
             { 0.05, i == 0 },
             { 0.8,  i == 1 }
           }
         ] (* probability of a high SAT score *)
     },
     BernoulliDistribution[θ]
   ]
];

(* conditional probability function for the Letter *)
cpdL = Function[ g,
   With[
     {
       θ = Piecewise[
             {
               { 0.9,  g == 1 },
               { 0.6,  g == 2 },
               { 0.01, g == 3 } 
             }
           ]
     },
     BernoulliDistribution[θ]
   ]
];

(* BayesNetwork = Joint Probability Distribution Function *)
(* B4 = P(I,D,G,L) *) 
distB4 = ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[ distI, i] PDF[ distD, d] PDF[ cpdG[i,d], g] PDF[ cpdL[g], l],
   {i, 0, 1, 1},
   {d, 0, 1, 1},
   {g, 1, 3, 1},
   {l, 0, 1, 1}
];

(* B5 = P(I,D,G,S,L) *)
distB5 = ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[ distI, i] PDF[ distD, d] PDF[ cpdG[i,d], g] PDF[ cpdS[i], s] PDF[ cpdL[g], l],
   {i, 0, 1, 1},
   {d, 0, 1, 1},
   {g, 1, 3, 1},
   {s, 0, 1, 1},
   {l, 0, 1, 1}
];
```

### Doing Inference

Now we would like to ask the question as stated above:

```
Probability[ g == 1 \[Conditioned] i == 1, {i,d,g,l} \[Distributed] distB4 ]
```

> 0.74

```
Probability[ g == 1 \[Conditioned] i == 1, {i,d,g,s,l} \[Distributed] distB5 ]
```

> Probability[ ] is returned unevaluted.

**Why is this the case? What can be done about it - after all 5 nodes should not be too far a stretch?**

Comment: One can also verify that the network `P(I,D,G,S)` will work without any problems, so it seems to be the number of nodes that causes trouble.

Comment: The problem also arises using `Which` instead of `Piecewise` or using functions with pattern tests, e.g. `cpdL[ g_?NumericQ] := ... `.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Beware of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

As indicated in the answer given by WRI [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129683/764), the interplay of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) and [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) is tricky and -- so my temporary verdict -- is best avoided.

Indeed, using indicator functions, e.g. [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html), as a replacement for `Piecewise` solves the issue:

```
(* nodes without parents remain unchanged *)
(* CPDs are redefined using Boole instead of Piecewise *)

(* conditional distribution of the grade *)
cpdG = Function[ {i,d},
   With[
      {
         p = Plus[
                {0.3 , 0.4 , 0.3 } Boole[ i == 0 && d == 0 ],
                {0.05, 0.25, 0.7 } Boole[ i == 0 && d == 1 ],
                {0.9 , 0.08, 0.02} Boole[ i == 1 && d == 0 ],
                {0.5 , 0.3 , 0.2 } Boole[ i == 1 && d == 1 ]
             ]
      },
      EmpiricalDistribution[ p -> Range[3] ]
   ]
];

(*conditional distribution for the SAT score*)
cpdS = Function[ i,
   With[
      {
         θ = Plus[
                0.05 Boole[ i == 0 ],
                0.8  Boole[ i == 1 ]
             ] (*probability of a high SAT score*)
      },
      BernoulliDistribution[θ]
   ]
];

(*conditional probability function for the Letter*)
cpdL = Function[ g,
   With[
      {
         θ = Plus[
                0.9  Boole[ g == 1 ],
                0.6  Boole[ g == 2 ],
                0.01 Boole[ g == 3 ]
             ]
      },
      BernoulliDistribution[θ]
   ]
];

(* B5 = P(I,D,G,S,L) complete BN *)
distB5 = ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[ distI, i] PDF[ distD, d] PDF[ cpdG[i,d], g] PDF[ cpdS[i], s] PDF[ cpdL[g], l],
   {i, 0, 1, 1}, {d, 0, 1, 1}, {g, 1, 3, 1}, {s, 0, 1, 1}, {l, 0, 1, 1}
];
```

Now doing inference for the complete joint probability distribution as specified by the Bayesian Network works out fine:

```
Probability[ g == 1\[Conditioned] i == 1, {i,d,g,s,l} \[Distributed] distB5 ]
```

> 0.74

Comment: Maybe (as a reminder) it is worth pointing out that within `Probability` the **order of the variables must match the one given by the distribution**. E.g. `Probability[ i == 1 \[Conditioned] d ==1 && g ==2, ... ]` will evaluate, but `Probability[ i == 1 \[Conditioned] g==2 && d==1,  ... ]` will not.

Comment: You might also consider using ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep[]`` to convert any `Piecewise[]` instance, if you find that representation troublesome.