# Issues with ProbabilityDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, estimation

I am trying to specify a user-defined probability distribution with `ProbabilityDistribution` and am running into errors when I try to obtain the distribution parameters for data using `EstimatedDistribution` in Mathematica.

```
(*Define the Distribution*)
ClearAll[stackheightfraction, BETDistribution, x, c];
stackheightfraction[x_, c_, k_Integer] := (1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1)*x) /; 
  k == 0
stackheightfraction[x_, c_, k_Integer] := 
 c*(1 - x)*(x^k)/(1 + (c - 1)*x) /; k > 0
BETDistribution[x_, c_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
   stackheightfraction[x, c, k], {k, 0, 1000, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> x > 0 && c >= 1 && x < 1] // Evaluate
```

I wanted the upper limit of k to be `Infinity` but after I settled for 1000 instead, I got `Mean`,`Variance`,`Skewness`, `PDF` and `CDF` to work with the distribution. However, I could not get `RandomVariate` to work.

```
{CDF[BETDistribution[.5, 5], 5], PDF[BETDistribution[.5, 5], 5], 
 Mean[BETDistribution[.5, 5]], Variance[BETDistribution[.5, 5]], 
 Skewness[BETDistribution[.5, 5]]}
```

I tested `PDF` and `CDF` using.

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BETDistribution[.75, 10], k], {k, 0, 5}, 
 ExtentSize -> Right, PlotRange -> All]
DiscretePlot[CDF[BETDistribution[.75, 10], k], {k, 0, 5}, 
 ExtentSize -> Right, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

But when I fit data, I run into issues:

```
data={0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10, 11, 10, 10, 5, 7, 5, 1, 12, 7, 7, \
12, 13, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 14, 6, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 19}

EstimatedDistribution[data, BETDistribution[xx, cc]]
```

I get output that looks likes this:

```
EstimatedDistribution[{0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2,
   1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10, 11, 10, 10, 
  5, 7, 5, 1, 12, 7, 7, 12, 13, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 14, 6, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 
  6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 19}, ProbabilityDistribution[stackheightfraction[xx, cc, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 0, 1000, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> xx > 0 && cc >= 1 && xx < 1]]
```

I am assuming that it has something to do with my `ProbabilityDistribution` because I had to add `\\Evaluate` before that that definition would work at k = 1.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  I get `RandomVariate` to work with version 12.0 (Windows 10) but not `EstimatedDistribution` with your example.

Comment: Have you tried using a Piecewise definition for your PDF instead of two separate functional expressions? It seems more logical here. Something like: `BETDistribution[x_, c_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[  Piecewise[{{(1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1)*x), k == 0}, {c*(1 - x)*(x^k)/(1 + (c - 1)*x), k > 0}}], {k, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1, c > 1}]`. That works with the `Infinity` term for $k$.

Comment: Once you get your distribution working, I would try out a few values of $xx$ and $cc$ (by hand or in a `Manipulate`) to see if you can match the calculated PDF of your distribution to the experimental PDF of your data (e.g. from `Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]`. That might give you better starting points for the `EstimatedDistribution`, or for `FindDistributionParameters`.

Comment: @MarcoB I am avoiding `Piecewise` like the plague in `ProbabilityDistribution` [(129690)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129690/764).

Comment: @gwr Good to know! I hadn’t come across the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For *Mathematica* verion 12.0 (Windows 10) `RandomVariate` works but `EstimatedDistribution` does not (nor does `FindDistributionParameters`).  So until someone figures this out, there are two relatively quick ways to get the maximum likelihood estimates and the associated standard errors for that family of distributions.

Both approaches below assume that there is at least one zero in the data.  The 3rd approach considers when there are no zeros in the data.

**Brute-force I:**

```
(* Generate data *)
SeedRandom[12345]
data = RandomVariate[BETDistribution[0.5, 5], 1000];

(* Construct log likelihood function *)
logL = LogLikelihood[BETDistribution[xx, cc], data];

(* Find maximum likelihood estimates of parameters *)
mle = Solve[D[logL, {{cc, xx}}] == 0, {cc, xx}][[1]]
(* {cc -> 357858/59675, xx -> 775/1621} *)

(* Find asymptotic standard errors and covariances of parameters *)
cov = -Inverse[D[logL, {{cc, xx}, 2}] /. mle];
ccSE = cov[[1, 1]]^0.5
(* 0.604096 *)
xxSE = cov[[2, 2]]^0.5
(* 0.0124068 *)
```

**Brute-force II:**

One notices that the maximum likelihood estimates are rational numbers.  This suggests that there is an explicit maximum likelihood solution.  The log of the likelihood can be written as

$$\log L=\log x \sum _{i=1}^{\infty } i f_i+ (n-f_0)\log c+n (\log (1-x)-\log ((c-1) x+1))$$

where $f_i$ is the observed frequency of the integer $i$. Using *Mathematica* code:

```
logL = n (Log[1 - x] - Log[1 + (-1 + c ) x]) + Log[x] Sum[i f[i], {i, 1, ∞}] + (n - f[0]) Log[c];
mle = Solve[D[logL /. Sum[i f[i], {i, 1, ∞}] -> sum, {{x, c}}] == 0, {x, c}][[1]]
```

[image: Maximum likelihood estimators of x and c]

```
cov = -Inverse[D[logL /. Sum[i f[i], {i, 1, ∞}] -> sum, {{x, c}, 2}] /. mle] // FullSimplify;
xxSE = Sqrt[cov[[1, 1]]]
```

[image: Standard error of estimator of x]

```
ccSE = Sqrt[cov[[2, 2]]]
```

[image: Standard error of estimator of c]

So what if we have a set of data?

```
(* Get frequency table *)
freq = Sort[Tally[data], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];
(* Number of observations *)
n = Length[data];
(* Number of zeros *)
f0 = freq[[1, 2]];
(* Sum of items times the associated frequency *)
sum = freq[[All, 1]].freq[[All, 2]];
(* Estimates *)
({xxMLE, ccMLE} = {(-n + sum + f0)/sum, -((n - f0)^2/((n - sum - f0) f0))}) // N
(* {0.4781, 5.99678} *)
(xxSE = Sqrt[((n - f0) (-n + sum + f0))/sum^3]) // N
(* 0.0124068 *)
(ccSE = Sqrt[((n - f0)^3 (-n^2 + sum f0 + n (sum + f0)))/(f0^3 (-n + sum + f0)^3)]) // N
(* 0.604096 *)
```

**Brute force III:  No zeros**

When there are no zeros in the data, the log of the likelihood is

$$\log L=\log x \sum _{i=1}^{\infty } i f_i + n\log c+n (\log (1-x)-\log ((c-1) x+1))$$

If we let `sum` $=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } i f_i$, then we write for the log likelihood

```
logL = Log[x] sum + n Log[c] + n (Log[1 - x] - Log[(c - 1) x + 1])
```

There is no solution that results in both partial derivatives being zero:

```
Solve[D[logL, {{x, c}}] == 0, {x, c}]
(* {} *)
```

Here a few step are skipped and the result is that the log of the likelihood is maximized with the estimate of $x$ being `1 - n/sum` and $c\rightarrow\infty$.

As an example suppose `data = {1,2,3,4,5}`.  Using `FindDistributionParameters`

```
FindDistributionParameters[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, BETDistribution[x, c]]
(* {c -> 58590.7, x -> 0.666669} *)
```

Note that the maximum likelihood estimator of `x` is `1 - n/sum = 1 - 5/15 = 2/3`.  If we choose a larger starting value for `c`, we'd get a much larger estimate of `c`.  So you can estimate `x` but not `c` when there are no zeros.

Comment: Thank you @JimB. I going to try both approaches with my data. I tried Brute Force-I with my `data ={0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10, 11, 10, 10, 5, 7, 5, 1, 12, 7, 7, \
12, 13, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 14, 6, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 19}`. For some reason, the cc values are less than 1 for some reason. I have to figure out why my `Assumption` c > 1 did not get enforced.

Comment: I wonder if my inconsistency in the order of the estimators is causing the confusion.  Brute-force I has `c` followed by `x` and Brute-force II has `x` followed by `c`.  I also see that for the standard errors in Brute-force I, I coded those in the wrong order.  I'll fix that.

Comment: But the estimates on your simulated data seemed fine. So I think that the parameter estimates are possibly telling me something about my data. But I am surprised that the `ProbabilityDistribution` did not the enforce `c≥1` constraint. By the way, your Mathematica coding is so surgical and elegant.

Comment: Thanks.  I do try to write things step-by-step.  And that's partly because I shy away from using lots of `@@@`'s (and similar constructions) unlike the really good folks here who can write all this stuff in a single line.  And step-by-step might be inefficient but it's a whole lot easier to debug.

Comment: I have a follow-up question for you. I ran into an odd situation. The Brute Force-I and Brute Force-II methods give exactly the same result for all data sets. However, when `f0=0` Brute Force-II throws a `ComplexInfinity` for `cc`. Brute Force-I gives proper estimates. Is there a tweak to Brute Force-II that would resolve this minor discrepancy. Here is one data set that is consistent and the other with a a `ComplexInfinity` .

Comment: Here are two data sets one works and the other does not: ```dataWorks={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 21}, dataDoesNotWork={5, 0, 2, 6, 2, 0, 8, 10, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5, 0}``` Thanks, again.

Comment: The code is now fixed where `f0` was incorrectly grabbing the first frequency assuming (incorrectly) that the first frequency concerned the number of zeros.  However, there is a problem obtaining the maximum likelihood estimates when there are no zeros.  I should have seen that from the division by `f0`.  I'll add a blurb about that in the next day or so.  I'll also address the problem with `LogLikelihood` not acknowledging the restriction on $c$ that you placed.

Answer (score 4):

This answer addresses your original limitation that

> I wanted the upper limit of `k` to be `Infinity` but after I settled for `1000` instead.

This is easily resolved if you had used `Piecewise[]` for the definition instead:

```
BETDistribution[x_, c_] :=
   ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{(1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1) x), k == 0}},
                                     c (1 - x) (x^k)/(1 + (c - 1) x)],
                           {k, 0, ∞, 1}, Assumptions -> c >= 1 && 0 < x < 1]
```

Then,

```
{CDF[BETDistribution[1/2, 5], 5], Mean[BETDistribution[1/2, 5]]}
   {187/192, 5/3}

data = {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4,
        2, 8, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10, 11, 10, 10, 5, 7, 5, 1, 12, 7, 7, 12, 13, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5,
        14, 6, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 19};
FindDistributionParameters[data, BETDistribution[xx, cc]]
   {cc -> 1., xx -> 0.808696}
```

Comment: +1 This also fixes the recognition of the lower bound on `cc` in the estimation process (which is lost in the brute-force approach with using the `LogLikelihood` function although that restriction can be added in - it's just not necessary with `FindDistributionParameters`).

Answer (score 3):

@J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties answer showed how to use `Piecewise` to obtain the desired definition which then allows `FindDistributionParameters` to work. But the question of generating random samples from this distribution still remains.

In *Mathematica* 12.1

```
RandomVariate[BETDistribution[1/2, 5], 10]
```

returns

[image: Warning message about sampling from the distribution is not implemented]

Fortunately in this case it is relatively easy and quick to generate a large random sample.  We separate the random selection of 0's and non-0's.  First a Bernoulli random number is selected with probability $1 - Pr[0] = 1 - (1 - x)/(1 + (-1 + c) x)$.  If that random number is zero, then `0` is selected.  If not, then it turns out that the random variable $Z|Z>0$ (where $Z\sim \text{BETDistribution}(x,c)$) has the same distribution of 1 plus a Geometric random variable with parameter `1 - x`.  Such a function can be written as

```
rvBET[x_, c_, nSamples_] := Module[{z1, z2},
  z1 = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1 - (1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1) x)], nSamples];
  z2 = 1 + RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[1 - x], nSamples];
  z1*z2
  ]
```

As a partial check on this consider generating a large amount of data with known parameters and then attempt to estimate the parameters:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = rvBET[1/4, 5, 100000];
FindDistributionParameters[data, BETDistribution[x, c]]
(* {c -> 4.9875, x -> 0.251256} *)
```

**Update:**

@J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties noted in a comment that the distribution could be written as follows:

```
BETDistribution[x_, c_] := TransformedDistribution[r1 (1 + r2), 
  {r1 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1 - (1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1) x)],
   r2 \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[1 - x]}, 
   Assumptions -> c >= 1 && 0 < x < 1]
```

Then this allows `RandomVariate` to work properly:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[BETDistribution[1/2, 5], 1000];
```

So no need for writing one's own functions to obtain random samples.

But there is one unforeseen downside:  `FindDistributionParameters` is much, much slower with this definition of `BETDistribution`.  With the above data and the newer definition of `BETDistribution` we have the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[FindDistributionParameters[data, BETDistribution[x, c]]]
(* {22.7427, {x -> 0.505552, c -> 5.37284}} *)
```

With the other definition we have

```
BETDistribution[x_, c_] := ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{(1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1) x),
  k == 0}}, c (1 - x) (x^k)/(1 + (c - 1) x)], {k, 0, ∞, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> c >= 1 && 0 < x < 1]

AbsoluteTiming[FindDistributionParameters[data, BETDistribution[x, c]]]
(* {0.0748486, {c -> 5.37284, x -> 0.505552}} *)
```

That's 300 times longer with the `TransformedDistribution`.  (The Rolling Stones said it long ago:  "You can't always get what you want.")

Comment: Your solution implies that one can also consider the definition `BETDistribution[x_, c_] := TransformedDistribution[r1 (1 + r2), {r1 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[1 - (1 - x)/(1 + (c - 1) x)], r2 \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[1 - x]}, Assumptions -> c >= 1 && 0 < x < 1]`; with that form, `RandomVariate[BETDistribution[1/2, 5], 20]` works without issues.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties  Good observation! (I wish I had thought of that!)  What do you suggest about adding that into one of the answers?  Or should that be another answer?  I'm not sure because its use is dependent on the specific distribution whereas at least two of the current answers (yours and one of mine) are more general approaches to such problems.

Comment: It's originally your idea, so please feel free to edit e.g. this answer to incorporate it.

Comment: Ah, that slowdown with `FindDistributionParameters[]` is quite unfortunate. There really is still a lot of room for improvement in handling custom distributions.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties  It is unfortunate.  But if I only had a small fraction of the power of *Mathematica* back in the 70's when I was a graduate student!  Our expectations keep increasing (which is a good thing but the history needs to be remembered).